# Preserve order when indexing a multilevel with a list

Tags: python, pandas

Using Pandas 0.20.2 with Python 3.6.1:

When you index a single-level DataFrame with a list, the returned DataFrame respects the order of the list, for example consider this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0,1,2], 
                   'col2': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']}, 
                  index=list('ABD'))
```

[image]

Which, when indexed with a list in a different order as the index, returns:

```
df.loc[['D','B'],:]
```

[image]

I would like to have exactly this behavior when i use a multi-index DataFrame. But if i add one of the columns to the index, and index again, the order is like the original DataFrame, instead of the list used for indexing:

```
df = df.set_index('col2', append=True)
df.loc[['D','B'],:]
```

[image]

Since the level contains strings, sorting the DataFrame before indexing is not as simple. A workaround could be to convert the index to Categorical, where the categories are mapped according to my preferred order, then a normal sort could work. But that seems really far-fetched, especially if you want different 'orders' all the time.

### edit:

@EdChum's answer works for the 2-level example i posted, but doesn't with a 3-level, so caution is needed!

Consider this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
                   'col2': ['green', 'blue', 'red'],
                   'col3': [0,1,2], }, 
                   index=list('ABD'))

df.index.names = ['col0']
df = df.set_index(['col1','col2'], append=True)
```

[image]

```
df.reindex(index=['baz', 'bar'], level='col1')
```

[image]

### edit2:

Trying @piRSquared's answer on the 3-level index, if you sort for the same level as the one your indexing with, it seems to be a solution.

```
df = df.sort_index(level='col1')
df.iloc[df.index.get_level_values('col1').searchsorted(['baz', 'bar'])]
```

[image]

Comment: This smells like a bug to me, `loc` should preserve the label order when returning rows based on the passed labels

Comment: It crossed my mind, but i couldn't find in the docs that the order is actually "guaranteed" by Pandas, or simply a side-effect, if it should, its a bug indeed. If someone knows this for sure, I'll file an issue on Github,

Comment: I suspect this is by design though as sortedness for multi-indices is recommended if not mandatory and I recall that if this isn't the case then label selection just won't work, it could be that recently they've decided to enforce this so you can't have an unsorted multi-index, what is surprising is why can't the order of the returned result match the order of the passed labels, it's worth posting on github to get a pandas dev's view on this

Comment: Maybe i will post it, if i can wrap my head around it. I figured with 1900 open issues, swamping them with questions like this is counter-productive. But if you look at my edit, it gets even weirder; when re-indexing a 3-level index. Its certainly confusing, perhaps `re-indexing`, isn't intended to be used for ordering after all.

Comment: For your update you could still `reindex` on `['D','B']` like before otherwise you'd have to chain your `reindex` calls like so: `df.reindex(index=['baz', 'bar'], level='col1').reindex(['D','B'],level='col0')`

Comment: Will that still work if "col1" has a 1-to-many relation with "col0", my example is a bit too simple perhaps since all levels have a 1-on-1 relation?

Comment: Don't know, possibly not in that case, it sometimes get's to the point where it becomes a hindrance having a multi-index due to the restrictions in place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-reindexing-and-alignment) to force the order of the rows in the order you desire, it seems that using `loc` it's not possible to do this with multi-indexes as sortedness is enforced always:

```
In[13]:
df.reindex(['D','B'], level=0)
Out[13]: 
        col1
  col2      
D baz      2
B bar      1
```

Comment: Thanks, much cleaner then the workaround i had in mind.

Comment: @RutgerKassies I was surprised that using `loc` doesn't work, it's probably by design but at least the `reindex` form isn't gnarly as the syntax for multi-index selection can look horrible to read

Comment: I tried a few `loc` options, eg being very explicit with `slice(None)` etc, the behavior remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the index is already sorted.

```
df1 = df.set_index('col2', append=True)

df1.iloc[df1.index.get_level_values(0).searchsorted(['D', 'B'])]

        col1
  col2      
D baz      2
B bar      1
```

---

But @EdChum's answer is far superior

Comment: Does (or should?) this still work if you don't use the first level, but for example the second or third? See my edits for a 3-level example DataFrame.

Comment: I see what you mean now, it should be sorted for the specific level you want to index on. Its not that bad actually.